# Where to get hard historical and trend data related to reentry of satellites like UARS

Tags: astronomy, nasa, satellites

NASA is providing very brief updates on the [reentry of the UARS satellite](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/uars/index.html).  They also published an extensive study of the [Re-entry and risk assessment for the NASA Upper Atmosphere Research Satellite (UARS)](http://www.nasa.gov/pdf/585584main_UARS_Status.pdf)

The Planetary Society Blog has some nice coverage and a graph of altitude over time: [Keeping track of UARS' reentry](http://planetary.org/blog/article/00003192/)

The well-known satellite tracking site Heavens Above site provides [UARS - Visible Passes](http://www.heavens-above.com/PassSummary.aspx?satid=21701&Session=kebgfdhakmplnnekcikpjceo) data which seems relatively up-to-date, but without information on the uncertainty.

What I want is actual tabular historical data, e.g. the changes in the [Orbital elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements) over the last months, weeks or days of its flight, and a characterization of how those elements other than altitude change over time.

***Update:*** The Center for Orbital and Reentry Debris Studies has a prediction and map for [UARS](http://reentrynews.aero.org/1991063b.html) orbits.

***Update 2:*** One authoritative source is [Space-Track](https://www.space-track.org/perl/login.pl), run by United States Strategic Command (USSTRATCOM), but you need to be an "approved registered user"....

Comment: This would probably be better suited to the [Space Exploration](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2949/space-exploration) proposal, as this isn't a space observing telescope, and even if it was, it has nothing to do with astronomy (heliophysics or ITM, maybe, but when I think prototypical astronomy questions, those aren't in it).  This would even be better in the physics site, but even that's pushing it.

Comment: And when you're searching for this type of data, the relevent term is 'ephemeris' or 'ephemerides'.  You can also try 'spice kernels', which refers to a specific format used by the [SPICE toolkit](http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/info/intrdctn.html).

Comment: @Joe thanks for the link to Space Exploration.  It doesn't seem very far along yet, not sure if it will fly.  The [faq] for Astronomy is pretty vague about what is on-topic, and I know there are lots of planetary astronomers and astrophysicists interested in orbit dynamics.  Given the stats for this site at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51/astronomy, I'd say more relevant questions would really help us get out of beta - we need 15/day, and only have 2/day now.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2:** I applied for, and quickly received, authorization for an account at  [Space-Track](https://www.space-track.org), as an amateur observer.  They let you download up to the 10 most recent TLEs for most satellites, and have alerts for reentries etc.

**Update 1**: For the Phobos-Grunt re-entry on 2012-01-15, there is a great archive of TLEs and predictions at [Phobos Grunt Re Entry Information - SPACEFLIGHT101](http://www.spaceflight101.com/phobos-grunt-re-entry-information.html).

For UARS, the best option I ran across was to watch [UARS Orbit Data at heavens-above.com](http://www.heavens-above.com/orbit.aspx?satid=21701&lat=0&lng=0&loc=Unspecified&alt=0&tz=CET) and copy/paste from there a few times.  The first two lines of each section are the "Two-Line Element Sets" - see [Orbital Elements at satobs.org](http://satobs.org/element.html) for an explanation of each number:

```
1 21701U 91063B   11267.10904230  .15227068  11945-4  11522-3 0  6420
2 21701 056.9313 262.1789 0003645 318.1436 041.9334 16.52554649109189

Epoch (UTC):    02:37:01, Saturday, September 24, 2011
Eccentricity:   0.0003645
Inclination:    56.9313°
Perigee height: 130 km
Apogee height:  135 km
Right Ascension of ascending node:  262.1789°
Argument of perigee:    318.1436°
Revolutions per day:    16.52554649
Mean anomaly at epoch:  41.9334°
Orbit number at epoch:  10918
```

---

```
1 21701U 91063B   11266.92730638  .09135854  11791-4  18500-3 0  6390
2 21701 056.9390 263.1012 0003809 338.0534 022.2824 16.46920535109153

Epoch (UTC):    22:15:19, Friday, September 23, 2011
Eccentricity:   0.0003809
Inclination:    56.939°
Perigee height: 145 km
Apogee height:  150 km
Right Ascension of ascending node:  263.1012°
Argument of perigee:    338.0534°
Revolutions per day:    16.46920535
Mean anomaly at epoch:  22.2824°
Orbit number at epoch:  10915
```